# Add edit fields on table row on click in reactjs without using react-table library

Tags: reactjs, html-table, edit, jsx

How to change a particular row that is clicked in JSX table to change to input editable row without using any libraries such as react-table?

```
<table className="table-data">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Section</th>
 </tr>   {this.state.students.map((item,key) => {return


<Fragment key={key}>
          <tr key={key} onClick={()=> 
    {this.setState({clientIsEditing:true},this.edit(key,item))}}> 
    <td>{item[1]}</td>    
    <td>{item[2]}</td>    
    <td>{item[3]}</td>  
    <td>{item[4]}</td> 
    </tr>  
    </Fragment>
    <tbody>
    </table>})}
```

the above is the code to display table. `this.state.students` has the student details from db. I want the particular table row to be changed to a row of input fields on click. Kindly help. I'm new to the world of react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you need to track additional state to determine if a "student" row is currently in editing mode or not. Perhaps you could achieve that by doing something like this:

```
<table className="table-data">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Section</th>
 </tr>   

 {  this.state.students.map((item,key) => {

    const editField = (value, index) => {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(item => ({ ...item }))

      // Update field by index of current student
      students[key][index] = value

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({ students })
    }

   return (
    <tr key={key} className={ item.editing ? 'editing' : '' } onClick={()=> {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(i => ({ ...i, editing : item.editing && i===item }))

      // Toggle editing flag of this current student (ie table row)
      students[key].editing = true; 

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({
        clientIsEditing:true, // This might not be needed ?
        students
      })
}
    }> 
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[1]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 1) } /> : <span>{item[1]}</span> }</td>    
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[2]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 2) } /> : <span>{item[2]}</span> }</td>    
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[3]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 3) } /> : <span>{item[3]}</span> }</td>  
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[4]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 4) } /> : <span>{item[4]}</span> }</td> 
    </tr>  )
  })
  }

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/1xjw49zk/) - hope that helps!

Comment: I get the following errors with the above code.. `TypeError: _this3.edit is not a function` and `'students' is not defined  no-undef` (in the onClick event)

Comment: The spread operator is throwing error  , `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ,` I'm sorry for being silly, I am completely new to React programming..

Comment: I'll try that. Meanwhile, could you pls tell me what is  editing in `item.editing`? where is the prop coming from

Comment: Sorry @dacre , it throws syntax error inside the onclick function.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes - yes, `editing` is initially undefined, however following user click of a table row, the `editing` field is added to a student and defined as `true`/`false` depending on toggling stated.

Comment: @Ar_11 no problems :-) All the best with your project!

Comment: Hi again, Could you help me with an addition to the above? how can I highlight the edited textbox instead of setting the state when clicked on next row?

Comment: Hi @Ar_11 , would you be able to open a new question and I can help you there?

Comment: pls find question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846290/highlight-textbox-on-edit.