# Highlight textbox on edit

Tags: reactjs, html-table, jsx

In continuation to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844544/add-edit-fields-on-table-row-on-click-in-reactjs-without-using-react-table-libra) , if I have a row that is currently being edited (via state), how do I keep the input textbox highlighted only if edited and stays highlighted even after clicking on next row?

My code looks like this:

```
<table className="table-data">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Section</th>
 </tr>   

 {  this.state.students.map((item,key) => {

    const editField = (value, index) => {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(item => ({ ...item }))

      // Update field by index of current student
      students[key][index] = value

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({ students })
    }

   return (
    <tr key={key} className={ item.editing ? 'editing' : '' } onClick={()=> {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(i => ({ ...i, editing : item.editing && i===item }))

      // Toggle editing flag of this current student (ie table row)
      students[key].editing = true; 

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({
        clientIsEditing:true, // This might not be needed ?
        students
      })
}
    }> 
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[1]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 1) } /> : <span>{item[1]}</span> }</td>    
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[2]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 2) } /> : <span>{item[2]}</span> }</td>    
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[3]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 3) } /> : <span>{item[3]}</span> }</td>  
    <td>{ item.editing ? <input value={item[4]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 4) } /> : <span>{item[4]}</span> }</td> 
    </tr>  )
  })
  }

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: When you say "highlight", do you mean visually change the input's appearance to show that can be edited?

Comment: By highlight ,I mean to visually show that the textbox has been edited,only if the input is changed. and, thanks for the edits. I'm new to stack overflow as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could achieve this - one way is to track additional state per student field to show highlighting in this way. One possiblitiy is to use a similar pattern to your current solution by means of the following:

```
render() {
    return (<table className="table-data">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Section</th>
 </tr>   

 {  this.state.students.map((item,key) => {

    const editField = (value, index) => {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(item => ({ ...item }))

      // Update field by index of current student
      students[key][index] = value

      // Extend state for student to tract editing history per field
      students[key].edited = students[key].edited || []
      students[key].edited[index] = true

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({ students })
    }

    // Returns true if the field by index has been edited. This is used for styling the td
    const isEdited = (index) => {
        const students = this.state.students.map(item => ({ ...item }))
        return (students[key].edited && students[key].edited[index] === true)
   }

   // Apply 'editing' class to the cell if it has been previously edited
   return (
    <tr key={key} className={ item.editing ? 'editing' : '' } onClick={()=> {

      // Clone students data before mutation
      const students = this.state.students.map(i => ({ ...i, editing : item.editing && i===item }))

      // Toggle editing flag of this current student (ie table row)
      students[key].editing = true; 

      // Trigger re-render
      this.setState({
        clientIsEditing:true, // This might not be needed ?
        students
      })
}
    }> 
    <td className={ isEdited(1) ? 'edited' : '' } >{ item.editing ? <input value={item[1]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 1) } /> : <span>{item[1]}</span> }</td>    
    <td className={ isEdited(2) ? 'edited' : '' } >{ item.editing ? <input value={item[2]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 2) } /> : <span>{item[2]}</span> }</td>    
    <td className={ isEdited(3) ? 'edited' : '' } >{ item.editing ? <input value={item[3]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 3) } /> : <span>{item[3]}</span> }</td>  
    <td className={ isEdited(4) ? 'edited' : '' } >{ item.editing ? <input value={item[4]} onChange={ e => editField(e.target.value, 4) } /> : <span>{item[4]}</span> }</td> 
    </tr>  )
  })
  }

  </tbody>
  </table>)
  }
```

To complete this, you would just need to add a CSS selector like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/7uspaot5/

For a working demo, [please see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uspaot5/) - hope this helps!

Comment: @Ar_11 you're welcome - please consider accepting this answer if it helped you :-)